# Is there a way to sort Eclipse tabs by activity?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

Eclipse is really slow to open and close tabs (and do anything really) so I tend to never close the tabs.

This means that the 6 tabs that you can see are generally not the files I am actually editing, and I either have to find the files in the Package Explorer, or use the double arrow drop down thing to the right of the tabs. Not a great experience.

Is there a way to sort tabs by most recently viewed or most recently edited?

Answer (score 1):

Go to 
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance 
and select "Classic" Theme

This fixed the random tab issue for me with WinXP

Found the solution here: http://thomas.trocha.com/wp/?p=762